# JavaScript iFrame to Parent postMessage issues

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I've been experiencing issues using `postMessage` in Firefox and Internet Explorer, whilst Google Chrome has worked sound as a pound each time.

What I'm trying to do is use `postMessage` from the iFrame to my parent with an action of `closeForm`. The iFrame URL is a sub-domain of the parent, the iFrame source itself also has `document.domain = document.domain` which I believe should have sorted my issues.

Currently the iFrame JavaScript is calling `window.top.postMessage('closeForm', '*')` which as I've mentioned works a treat in Chrome, but in Firefox I get `ReferenceError: window is undefined` so I changed `window.top` to `parent.postMessage` but I get get the same thing only with `parent is not defined`.

The same thing doesn't work in IE9 either. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm happily using [jQuery postMessage](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/), it provides you with a fallback in case a browser doesn't support `postMessage`. Try it out!

Comment: But Firefox does support it, likewise does IE8 (which we support to), I'll check it out, but there should be a solution to this right?

Comment: Well it is indeed supposed to work, but without any code, that's how far I can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look - Ben's iframe resize example works in Firefox, so I'll have to check it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`window.parent` works for me in Firefox on OS X

Comment: Okay, well could you try going to http://caribbeanwarehouse.co.uk/hotels/mexico/excellence_riviera_cancun.php and clicking 'Request a Callback' use the details; Test as both names and test@test.com as the email, watch the Firebug console in Firefox.

Comment: yup, "window is not defined" on clicking "return to website"

Comment: have you tried calling a function other than postMessage() on the main page?  Maybe it's a FF bug specific to postMessage...

Comment: Yeah, I split `closeForm` into a separate function and tried calling that rather than `postMessage`.

Comment: ah, maybe it's a cross domain thing - caribbeanwarehouse.co.uk in the main page vs cb.caribbeanwarehouse.co.uk in the iframe

Comment: That's what was originally the problem, however I tried doing `document.domain = document.domain` as I read somewhere and nothing changed? Should I hard code the domain name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16485/discussion-between-rob-agar-and-james)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're having trouble using the `postmessage`. You can use the jQuery `postMessage`. This is what i used in some iframe cross-domain issues and it worked. Here is the example.

[jQuery postMessage](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/)